# Browse Button in Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework

I want to add a browse button in Zend_Form to upload Image files..

Answer (score 2):

why you dont use Zend_Form_Element_File ?
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.file

Comment: why not ? show some code, (i know of a bug in 1.6 which was fixed in 1.6.2 where no decorators where set for file elements)

Answer (score 1):

See [`Zend_File_Transfer`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.html#zend.file.transfer.introduction):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.file.html#zend.file.transfer.introduction